# Messenger - Chatbot without creating FB App for each Page

Tags: chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot

I built a chatbot that I plan to use with my pages. It's nothing special, only for development purposes. I used fastapi + mongodb + RASA NLU. It's all working fine with the integration by creating the app and subscribe to the webhook. the only problem I have is that I need to create one app per page. **How can I link my chatbot to my page without creating an app all the time?** I noticed ManyChat and ChatFuel can do this but I'm lost the fb developer documentation.

for reference, here's my current webhook setup.

```
https://myapp.com/webhook/<pageid_01>/
https://myapp.com/webhook/<pageid_02>/
https://myapp.com/webhook/<pageid_03>/
```

it's a workaround, of course. it works but I don't really want to maintain too many fb apps. not that I have many but between me and my friends who want to use my chatbot, it's not a pretty sight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same webhook to handle events from multiple pages, but i don't think there is a way to make one fb messenger app for multiple pages! because the app will be receiving page-scoped unique Ids

Comment: you're correct. After I posted the question, I realized I can get the pageid from the payload so I can use the same webhook for all the apps. but I still need to create multiple apps which is what I'm trying to achieve. anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just connect multiple pages to same app. And when you receive the event on your webhook, you can check the page-id and based on page-id, perform that page specific actions.

Comment: am not exactly sure if I followed you because I can't do that (at least as of now).

my current workaround is as below.

page 1 --> app 1 --> webhook one
page 2 --> app 2 --> webhook one
page 3 --> app 3 --> webhook one

what I want to achieve is 
page 1 --> app 1 --> webhook one
page 2 --> app 1 --> webhook one
page 3 --> app 1 --> webhook one
can you point me how to do it?